# jquery post, error reporting, serialize not working. tried everything else

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to communicate with php usring jquery ajax method.

```
<form class="form-group" id="formm" action="check.php" method="post">
        <label for="">Testing</label><br>
        <input type="text" class="col-md-5" id="name" placeholder="" name="name"><br>
        <button type="button" name='button' id="button" class="btn  btn-default" type="submit">button</button>
        <p class="help-block" id="result">Help text here.</p>
      </form>
```

my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#button").click(function(){
        $.post("check.php", $( "#formm :input" ).serialize(), function(info) {
          $("#result").html(info);
        });
      });
    });
    $("#button").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

my php code

```
 if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test") or die ("Couldnt connect");

    $check = "INSERT INTO name WHERE name='$username'";

    $sql_check = mysqli_query($con,$check);

      if($sql_check) {
          echo "Successfully inserted";
        } else {
            echo 'Couldnt Insert';
          }
    }
```

Now, js script is communicating with php but not as i want it to.
 1. when i use serialize(), it stops communicating
 2. When i dont use serialize(), my php code sends me back "Couldnt insert"
 3. I tried using php errors reporting lines, js doesnt communiate again. No errors on console either.
 Is there something i am missing?

UPDATE : tried serializing just the formm and not the input element, still not working.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: nothing on console. its empty

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: Not the console - the request/response in the network tab

Comment: its for practice purpose, so i am not using prepared statements.

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."* or *"Ignore the security risk..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: in the network log, i can see check.php But it doesnt return any value from the php file

Comment: Just use `$( "#form" ).serialize()` [Can you see what the call is sending to the PHP?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: i did. no response.

Comment: Does the PHP work when called without AJAX?

Comment: You're not sending a `button` parameter in the request and your PHP code doesn't do anything if the post request doesn't contain a `button` parameter because of the `if(isset($_POST['button']))` statement.

Comment: i tried just the php code, it gives me "Couldnt insert"

Comment: You need to get the actual error from `mysqli_error($con)` rather than your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some warnings:

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

---

I have been looking for the wrong error all along. Your `INSERT` query syntax is wrong, you cannot use `WHERE` in an `INSERT` query.

Change `INSERT INTO name WHERE name='$username'` to `INSERT INTO name_of_table (name_of_column) VALUES('$username')`

Comment: Apologies for my temporary blindness. If error reporting had been on the PHP would have returned an error which would've pointed us in the right direction earlier. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Serialize Form not the inputs

```
$.post("check.php", $( "#formm" ).serialize(), function(info) {
      $("#result").html(info);
    });
```

Comment: just tried. No communication with php. nothing on console either.

Comment: why not try using $.ajax({ ... })

Comment: im not sure.. i also think jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] ) is the syntax of that..try puting url

Comment: Because `.post()` is a jQuery `.ajax()` shorthand @Arianne

Comment: in the network log, i can see check.php But it doesnt return any value from the php file